# How to store a number (coming from cookie) into query vars for later usage in other filters?

Tags: functions, theme-development, pages, child-theme, cookies

I have a small HTML5 game playable (as "canvas") at different social networks, which sets an HTTP cookie.

When a player comes to my WordPress site (acting as help and support website for the game), I can fetch her id from the cookie (and verify it wasn't faked - by calculating hash and fetching from database) with my custom method:

```
$my_id = fetchCookie();
```

**My question:** how to perform parsing the cookie *just once* and then pass the user id around?

In the `functions.php` file of my child theme I have put:

```
add_filter( 'query_vars','my_insert_query_vars' );

function my_insert_query_vars( $vars )
{
    array_push( $vars, 'my_id' );
    return $vars;
}
```

and plan to call `get_query_var( 'my_id', 0 )` whenever the user id is needed in other filters in the same file.

But where and how should I set that variable?

**In other words:** where to call `$my_id = fetchCookie()` and how to store the returned value into "query vars"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cookie is stored on the user's computer. The page is generated on the server. Somehow, you must make sure the cookie is transported back to the server when the user clicks on a link to fetch a second page.

The instrument for this is javascript. You must send a script with the page that reads the cookie and adds the cookie content as a `query_var` to any internal link, so when it is clicked the `query_var` is sent to the server.

1. Make the script to read the cookie. I trust you have already done
   this.
2. In your theme, make sure [all internal links have a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713222/add-class-to-all-links-that-link-to-a-certain-domain-with-js-jquery)
   that you can use to trigger a script that will in turn trigger the
   cookie script and [add the `query_var` to the url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15652251/add-variable-to-end-of-href-url-onclick-jquery).

I realise this answer is incomplete in terms of code, but I hope you get the idea.